# SCons: Jar Builder: How do you add resource files (foo.properties, bar.gif, etc.)

Tags: scons

When I try to add resources to the source list of a env.Jar(), SCons tries to compile the resources.  The code in jar.py looks like it should check for the JAVASUFFIX and just leave non-'.java' files alone, but it doesn't work for me.  Suggestions?

Comment: can you specify what type of non-java files you're trying to add to the Jar, and also a sample SConstruct, and the output from SCons that you're seeing. (also what platform, version of python, version of SCons, version of java)

Comment: I'm trying to look at this, and it doesn't look like they're handled - there is in fact a testcase, but the part that would confirm the file got added is commented out like: `# TODO: determine expected behavior with resource files` as if that were an unsolved question. Running the testcase, the .txt file seems to be omitted from the jar, not erroneously compiled.  As @bdbaddog asks - do you have a simple example we could diagnose with?

Comment: I cobbled together a bit of a test, and now I see it does pick up (without compiling) non-java files - perhaps you're not getting the file installed/copied to the place the jar is made from? More info would make it easier to provide the requested suggestions!

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be related to where the files are.  In my case, I'm keeping the original Java and resource files in a source hierarchy.  Then I compile them to a binary (like an object directory for C/C++) directory.  I created a Command to copy the properties files and update them with a version number.   If I use the target from the Command builder for the Jar source, then it looks to be working.  I was hoping to use the return from the env.Command(... Copy) invocation as the object to add to the Jar sources list, but that seems to be wrong.

Comment: If you're able to hop over onto the SCons Discord (a web search should find that) we may be able to help you a bit more interactively.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.